# What's the best way to stop site visitors seeing the contents of a folder?

Tags: security, .htaccess, url

I have a list of documents here: www.example.com/documents

I want to key the documents folder in the public_html / htdocs folder (not above it). However, I don't want people to be able to navigate to www.example.com/documents or for Google to index the content. But I still need to use links to the documents across the site (mainly within a logged in area).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance I misunderstood the question, but I think you'd like to disable directory listing. If so, just put

```
Options -Indexes
```

in your .htaccess file. This tells Apache not to create that fancy file list when the URI http://example.com/directory/ is requested, so the user will get a 404 error. Reqests to files within the directory are unaffected.

You can also do various fancy things with the directory listing by using the [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) directives like IndexIgnore.

Comment: Thanks. How secure is this? ie. is it possible for "smarter" users to see a list of files?

Comment: Not very secure. This method just hides the index from appearing, but the files within the directory will stay accessible, so Google will be able to index it (use robots.txt to prevent that), and a user may be able to retrieve the content if he knows (or guesses) the filename. If you need security, put the documents in a secure place (a level above htdocs), and serve the content via an intermediate script that contains access verification (I think it's good practice anyway). Then again, I don't know exactly what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I've put them above public_html